# Using Vue js Grid layout grid items as cards

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [Vue Grid Layout](http://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) plugin to create a dashboard that i can move items around and resize.These are inbuilt behaviors of this plugin already but i need to add some more features like making each grid item a card with a title and a button. because of this the layout formats get messed up and overlaps with each other.

```
<grid-layout
        :layout.sync="children"
        :col-num="12"
        :row-height="60"
        :is-draggable="true"
        :is-resizable="true"
        :is-mirrored="false"
        :vertical-compact="true"
        :margin="[10, 10]"
        :auto-size="true"
        :prevent-collision="true"
        :use-css-transforms="true"
        @layout-updated="layoutUpdatedEvent"
      >
        <grid-item
          v-for="child in children"
          :x="child.x"
          :y="child.y"
          :w="child.w"
          :minW="1"
          :h="child.h"
          :minH="3"
          :i="child.i"
          :is-draggable="true"
          :is-resizable="true"
          :key="child.i"
        >
          <div class="dab-card">
            <div class="btn-content b-bottom">
              <div class>
                <button class="red-ico-btn" @click="deleteChart(child.id)">
                  <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class>
                <h6>{{ child.title }}</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            <component
              :is="child.type"
              :key="child.i"
              :data="child.chart.data"
              :tableDataCopy="child.chart.data"
              :headers="columns"
              :x_axis="child.chart.x"
              :y_axis="child.chart.y"
              :id="child.i"
              :dashboard_data_id="child.id"
              :colors="child.chart.colors"
            ></component>
          </div>
        </grid-item>
      </grid-layout>
```

currently layout does not contain items in its borders or it doesn't resize with the grid-item resizing,grid-items does not adjust each other to respective rows and columns when a nearby item is resized or moved.

[image: current look of the layout]

this is the css used for the dab-card class:

```
.dab-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: #f1f1f1 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you add details of your plugin, like link to its page, version used etc might be helpful? Also a screenshot of your problem can also help.

Comment: https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout
This is the link for the plugin

Comment: Is that card styles from another plugin or your own styles? Did you checked any style conflict between `dab-card` class and your grid layout plugin styles? Start by removing any `position` or `display` properties in your `dab-card` style and check if it helps.

Comment: Please don't add details in comments. Add to the question itself.

Comment: Instead what i think the problem is using the grid_item inside the cards. cards do not hold a position as a grid-item, the component do. in that case component gets in place to the given X and Y axis but cards collapse with each other. i need a solution to place the positions on cards to begin with.

Comment: In your example code above, there are unmatched closing div tags after component tag

Comment: yes i removed them now. i commented a part of the code but forgot to remove the divs